# Determine if the checkbox is checked on click event in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

I have this checkbox control:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id: 'prefix_12', attributeid: 12, poseId: $parent.Id }, click: $root.addEffect" />
                                            Add Option
```

And the event code:

```
self.addEffect = function (c, event) {
    var target = event.target;
}
```

What I want to know is how can I determine if the checkbox is checked or unchecked for each click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.currentTarget`

```
if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
  // do the stuff
}
else {
 // do the stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The knockout way would be to bind checkbox against boolean property like this

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: someBoolProperty" />
```

In viewmodel

```
self.someBoolProperty = ko.observable();
```

And rather than use click event, subscribe to the property

```
self.someBoolProperty.subscribe(function(newValue){
    if (newValue){
        // do whatever you want to do for checked checkbox
    } else {
        // unchecked
    }
}, self);
```